# Global BeforeEach for mocking HTTP request with Mocha and Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, unit-testing, mocha.js

I have few requests that are triggered in `module.run`:

```
angular.module('demo').run(function($http) {
  $http.get('/some/thing');
  $http.get('/some/other/thing');
});
```

And when I use `$rootScope.$apply` in my tests to resolve mock promises, I get `unexpected request errors` for `'/some/thing'` and `'/some/other/thing'`.

One way to fix it is to set `$httpBackend` in the beforeeach:

```
$httpBackend.when('GET', mockData.API_URL + '/some/thing').respond(200, {});
$httpBackend.when('GET', mockData.API_URL + '/some/other/thing').respond(200, {});
```

This will work but it means that I have to put it into beforeeach of every test file where I use `$rootScope.$apply`.

**How can I make those `$httpBackend` configs global for every test file?

Or is there a better solution to this problem?**

Answer (score 2):

From the [Mocha website](https://mochajs.org/), at "Root-Level Hooks":

> You may also pick any file and add "root"-level hooks. For example,
>   add beforeEach() outside of all describe() blocks. This will cause the
>   callback to beforeEach() to run before any test case, regardless of
>   the file it lives in (this is because Mocha has a hidden describe()
>   block, called the "root suite").

```
beforeEach(function() {   
    console.log('before every test in every file'); 
});
```

Answer (score 1):

If you really need it in *all* tests VinceOPS answer is best. What I would do if you don't need it in *every* test but just a lot is move the $httpBackend calls into a separate function and put that in a shared js file. Then you just call that function from beforeEach when needed.

For more complex configurations I often create my own wrapper functions for either `describe()`, `it()` or the function where you define the test to prevent writing (too much) duplicate code.